# Is G-d still present in a relationship continuing after a Get?

Tags: divorce

I would like to know that if after two Jews are divorced what is the relationship with G-d and their relationship. It is said that G-d is part of a marriage and continues to be. If the couple gets divorced, where does G-d stand in this relationship now? I know what happens when the relationship is broken up through illegal acts such as adultery, but what happens when it is mutual and done according to G-d's law?

Comment: What relationship is there still after the Get?

Comment: Since the relationship is completely severed, then Hashem would be *there* in the same way that he is *there* between any two Jews.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to hear about a difficult situation; hello and welcome to J.SE.

The Gemara speaks about the presence of God dwelling between a married couple. A *Get* ends a marriage. At that point, as sabbahillel commented, God is present the same way as between any two individuals; the relationship is no longer a marital one.

I recognize that some couples who've gone through a *Get* stay on friendly terms, and in other cases it can be quite vitriolic.

In some tragic cases, a *Get* is really the best (or least-bad) solution for everyone involved, which is why the Torah clearly allowed for divorce. No one should ever feel guilty (or be made to feel guilty) about what happens to the Divine Presence in that situation.

Comment: Without sources that answer seems to just be an opinion. Not very useful.

Comment: @mevaqesh - This entire question seems opinion based, almost. I'm having difficulty determining exactly what the OP means and wants for an answer.

Comment: @ezra I don't see how it's any more opinion based than any other theological question which can't be determined exactly. The question seems fairly clear: there is an aggada about the shekhina expressing itself in a marriage, which I assume the op is asking about, and the question is whether this applies after marriage as well. Not the clearest, but not too bad.